# Утечка памяти при работе с QAxObject

Tags: c++, windows, qt, com, утечка-памяти

Прошу прощения, что много кода, просто уже несколько недель не могу убрать утечку. Проверяю просто вызовом функции getPointingDevices в цикле, вот описание класса и методов:

```
class SystemInfo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SystemInfo(QString lpRemoteName = ".");
    ~SystemInfo();
    QVector<QPair<QString, QString>> getPointingDevices();

private:
    QAxObject *objWMIService; // не удалять
    QAxObject *objInterList; // не удалять
    QAxObject *item = 0;
    QString query;

    bool initializeItem(IEnumVARIANT *enumInterface);
    IEnumVARIANT *halfInitialize();
};

SystemInfo::SystemInfo(QString lpRemoteName)
{
    if (lpRemoteName == "")
        lpRemoteName = ".";

    QAxObject *objIWbemLocator = new QAxObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");

    QObject::connect(objIWbemLocator, SIGNAL(exception(int, QString, QString, QString)), this, SLOT(wmi_error(int,QString,QString,QString)));
        if (!objIWbemLocator)
        qDebug("Не создался WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");

      objWMIService = objIWbemLocator->querySubObject(
              "ConnectServer(QString&,QString&)", //objWMIService - объявляем как переменную член класса, память выделяем в конструкторе
              lpRemoteName, QString("root\\cimv2")); // пространство имен. Если и домен и рабочая группа, можно прикрутить аутентификацию
      if (!objWMIService)
      {
        qDebug("Не создался WMIService");
        objIWbemLocator->clear();
        objIWbemLocator->deleteLater();
        throw "error";
      }
      objIWbemLocator->clear();
      objIWbemLocator->deleteLater();
}

SystemInfo::~SystemInfo()
{
    objWMIService->clear();
    objWMIService->deleteLater();
}

QVector<QPair<QString, QString> > SystemInfo::getPointingDevices()
{
    QVector<QPair<QString, QString>> vec;
    query = QString("SELECT * FROM Win32_PointingDevice");
    IEnumVARIANT *enumInterface = halfInitialize();
    if (enumInterface != nullptr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objInterList->dynamicCall("Count").toInt(); i++)
        {
            if (initializeItem(enumInterface))
            {
                vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Имя устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("Name").toString()));
                vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Описание устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("Description").toString()));
                vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Id устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("DeviceID").toString()));
                vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Интерфейс устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("DeviceInterface").toString()));
                vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Тип устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("HardwareType").toString()));

                item->deleteLater();
            }
        }
        objInterList->deleteLater();
        enumInterface->Release();
    }

    return vec;
}

bool SystemInfo::initializeItem(IEnumVARIANT *enumInterface)
{
    VARIANT *theItem = (VARIANT*)malloc(sizeof(VARIANT));
    if (enumInterface->Next(1,theItem,NULL) == S_FALSE)
      return false;

    item = new QAxObject((IUnknown*)theItem->punkVal);
    free(theItem);
    if (!item)
    {
        item->deleteLater();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

IEnumVARIANT* SystemInfo::halfInitialize()
{
    objInterList = objWMIService->querySubObject("ExecQuery(QString&))", query);
    if (!objInterList)
      return nullptr;

    if (objInterList->dynamicCall("Count").toInt() == 0)
      return nullptr;

    QAxObject *enum1 = objInterList->querySubObject("_NewEnum");
    if (!enum1)
      return nullptr;

    IEnumVARIANT* enumInterface = 0;
    enum1->queryInterface(IID_IEnumVARIANT, (void**)&enumInterface);

    enum1->deleteLater();

    if (!enumInterface)
      return nullptr;

    enumInterface->Reset();
    return enumInterface;
}
```

UPD: Установил путём умного комментирования, что основная проблема в этом месте:

```
if (initializeItem(enumInterface))
{
      vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Имя устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("Name").toString()));
      vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Описание устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("Description").toString()));
      vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Id устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("DeviceID").toString()));
      vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Интерфейс устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("DeviceInterface").toString()));
      vec.push_back(QPair<QString, QString>("Тип устройства ввода", item->dynamicCall("HardwareType").toString()));

      item->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: вы знаете что такое `valgrind`?

Comment: Нет, но гугл подсказал, что это отладчик использования памяти. У меня же windows, а она для Unix систем, так что не вариант

Comment: А вы смотрели, что возвращает "enumInterface->Release();"  ? Можете поделиться?

Comment: Каждый раз возвращает 1

Comment: Попробовал 
        enumInterface->Release(); перенести в функцию initializeItem, т.е. на каждой итерации вызывалась, всё также возвращало единицу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool SystemInfo::initializeItem(IEnumVARIANT *enumInterface)
{
    VARIANT *theItem = (VARIANT*)malloc(sizeof(VARIANT));//Выделили память
    if (enumInterface->Next(1,theItem,NULL) == S_FALSE)//Если условие выполнилось
      return false;//выходим и память утекла

    item = new QAxObject((IUnknown*)theItem->punkVal);//Если new выбросит исключение, то
    free(theItem);//до сюда не дойдем и память утечет
    if (!item)//если переделать new на версию, возвращающую 0 в случае ошибки, то
    {//при ошибке выделения освобождать тоже нечего, тем более, item будет равен нулю и
        item->deleteLater();//это тоже самое, что nullptr->deleteLater()
        //но new в данном коде бросает исключение в случае ошибки, так что это условие заведомо бесполезно
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```